# What advantages it gets building a website from scratch on behalf of the amount of free/cheap themes on the internet?

Tags: wordpress, web, themes, frontend

Ok, so suppose I want to open an online shop, an eCommerce website. I saw that you can do that by simply customizing a wordpress theme in a couple of hours; a domain and a webhosting and you're done, right?

Why should someone hire me and pay me a generous sum of money if he can do it himself? What advantages brings writting code from scratch?

I ask this from the position of a rookie technology learner, developer wanna be, and I am still at the point at choosing my direction.

Comment: theme from scratch is always better, faster and ligther if you code it the right way compare to "premium themes", though I prefer to use solid and light theme framework

Comment: alright, when I said from scratch I was thinking at using frameworks, not reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just that easy.  Not everyone is good with computers.  You pay a web developer not only for knowing the best way to implement the system but organization of the website, configuring the server the best way etc.  Even high end companies don't write from scratch because it's too time consuming. Time = Money and most businesses don't have that kind of budget.

But they do need someone that can fix their store if something goes wrong.  Every second the site is down, that's money lost.